# How to retrieve name of employee having salary greater than the average salary of their respective department

Tags: sql-server

I have a table  named "tblEmployee". Columns in this table are "EmpId","Department","Salary".
Rows in this table are as follows(e1,sales,10000),(e2,hr,20000),(e3,sales,30000),(e4,production,40000),(e5,hr,50000).
I want to retrieve name of the employee whose salary is greater than the average salary of their  respective department.I want solution for sql server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at [group by](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx). This will let you calculate average salary per department. Then you can simply join on resulting set to find employees with salaries greater than average.

Answer (score 4):

```
select emp.EmpId, emp.Department
  from tblEmployee emp
  where emp.Salary > ( select
                           avg(emp2.Salary)
                         from tblEmployee emp2
                         where emp2.Department = emp.Department
                     )
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding an aggregate by using an the OVER clause to generate in-line AVG

```
;WITH cte as
(
    select
       EmpId, Department, Salary,
       AVG(Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY Department) AS DeptAvgSal
    FROM
       tblEmployee
)
SELECT
   EmpId, Department, Salary
FROM
   cte
WHERE
   Salary > DeptAvgSal
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Though I would just a do inline select and inner join on it since CTE is not universally supported.

Comment: @liho1eye: true, but assuming SQL Server the CTE and OVER clause were both added in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
select e.eid,e.did,e.ename,e.sal,t.avg_sal dpt_avg_sal from emp e inner join
(select emp.did, AVG(sal) avg_sal from emp inner join dpt on emp.did = dpt.did
group by emp.did) t
on  e.did = t.did where e.sal > avg_sal
```

Answer (score 0):

Where @department is the passed-in parameter denoting which department...

```
select * from tblEmployee where Salary > 
  (select AVG(Salary) from tblEmployee where Department = @department)
and Department = @department
order by salary desc
```

Comment: and for all departments on one query?

Comment: @gbn As andr displayed, match the department in the nested query to the one in the outer. Very easy change from my answer. This is just the way I thought of it initially, since Himanshu didn't specify how it was to be searched...